# Latitude Longitude search query not working

Tags: mysql, spatial, myisam

My table has following Lat and Longs:

```
Lat & Longs are... 1.330690209415938,103.92820715904236
Lat & Longs are... 1.3292425419208693,103.92836272716522    
Lat & Longs are... 1.328588258949486,103.9237603917718
Lat & Longs are... 1.3316555440643845,103.92398569732904
Lat & Longs are... 1.3310709803501815,103.9254716411233
Lat & Longs are... 1.3326560728062167,103.91472470015287
Lat & Longs are... 1.3327150654429698,103.91202673316002
Lat & Longs are... 1.3340789345882447,103.87714426964521
```

When I run this below query , it is not returning anything. Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    geomit
WHERE   MBRContains(LineFromText(CONCAT(
        '('
        , 1.330690209415938 + 10 / ( 111.1 / cos(RADIANS(1.330690209415938)))
        , ' '
        , 103.92820715904236 + 10 / 111.1
        , ','
        , 1.330690209415938 - 10 / ( 111.1 / cos(RADIANS(1.330690209415938)))
        , ' '
        , 103.92820715904236 - 10 / 111.1 
        , ')' ))
        ,latlong);
```

Note: my create table script is:

```
CREATE TABLE geomit (
 latitude double,
 longitude double,
 latlong GEOMETRY NOT NULL,
 SPATIAL INDEX(latlong)) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: FYI, that `CONCAT` generates `(1.420674936107291 104.01821615904236, 1.2407054827245851 103.83819815904236)` .

Answer (score 0):

Is it write to compare a line (not a polygon) with points?

Perhaps you need to build a rectangle, not a line, from those two points plus another two?